# Regex for files path

Tags: php, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate the path of an uploaded file in php, that must be validated with regular expressions and not with native functions.

The path that I'm getting is:

```
C:\xampp\tmp\php33DB.tmp
```

So, when I test this path with `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_:\\]*\Z/` returns false.(I think it's because the path have the backward slashes `\` )

There's a way to validate the path for Linux and Windows servers of the files uploaded in PHP only with regex?

Comment: You forgot the colon : .

Comment: Try replacing all instances of a back slash on a windows path to a forward slash. If you open command prompt you can still access files via / or \.

Comment: use `#^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\\\:-]+#`

Comment: What are you actually trying to validate? That's a temporary file *created by PHP* which holds the actual file uploaded by the user, what could be invalid about it? The path of the temporary file depends on your PHP configuration.

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez If you want to use the backward slash you have to escape it properly by using \\\\.

Comment: @Akam post your answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$text = 'C:\xampp\tmp\php33DB.tmp';
preg_match("#^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\\\:.-]+#",$text,$out);
print_r($out);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php33DB.tmp )
```

However, this file is temporary file that created by PHP upload, I think no need to validate it because it was created by server not client, you can just check the mime type of uploaded file, and check is_uploaded_file() if the file was uploaded by HTTP Post.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this function instead: `file_exists`

So in your code you could do:

```
if (file_exists($tmpFile)) {
    // ... do stuff
}
```